# SumIfs VBA function not working properly in macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a form that is supposed to show the total sum of different numeric values between two dates, a start date and a finish date. For this, I thought the best option would be to use the `SumIfs` `WorkSheetFunction`. However, after trying to code this, the function is not working properly. I am not sure of what is wrong. If I type the exact same formula on the worksheet that has the table with my sample data, it works perfectly.

So, the form I designed is the following:

[image]

A second label and textbox will be added for the finish (or end) date. However, I thought it would be better to do that once I get the code to work with a single date in the beginning. The textbox where the user will insert the start date is called `tbxDate` and the textbox that will show the resulting sum is called `tbxBalance`. The button that triggers the `SumIfs` functions is called `cmdCalculate`.

Also, the table that stores the data (which only has one row of data so far for testing purposes) is this one:

[image]

The table name is `Sales`, and the worksheet name is `SalesWS`. I thought the code should be pretty simple, unless there is something I am missing. What I did was:

```
Private Sub cmdCalculate_Click()

  Set SalesRange = Worksheets("SalesWS").Range("Sales[TOTAL]")
  Set DatesRange = Worksheets("SalesWS").Range("Sales[DATE]")
  tbxBalance = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(SalesRange , DatesRange , ">=" & tbxDate)

End Sub
```

The issue is that the `>=` part of the criteria is failing. I only get proper results using only the greater than or less than conditions. For example, if I enter the date 09/08/2020 in the textbox the result in the balance textbox is 0, but if I enter the date 08/08/2020 or anything before it works. It just ignores the condition to sum the values if the date is equal to what is entered. It only works with dates greater or less than what the user inputs in the textbox, excluding the chosen date.

I already checked that the column with the dates in the table is formatted properly.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld That's because if I do so the code breaks even more. If I put `Dim tbxDate As Date` before anything else, no matter what date I input in the textbox, it sums everything in the table. And if I do `CDate(tbxDate)` in the last argument of the `SumIfs` formula, nothing changes. It just adds dates greater or less than what I enter, not equal dates as well.

Comment: What is the data type of the dates in your date column?

Comment: If you are getting those funny results, there is probably something wrong with your data types. It is almost never a good idea to have all your data types as being of type variant.

Comment: The table columns that stores all the dates is formatted as date with the `dd/mm/yyyy` format. If I dim the textbox as date nothing works. Any suggestions?

Comment: Make sure you don't compare apples with pears. Your "tbxDate" stands for `tbxDate.Value` which is a string that looks like a date. If you have similar strings in the *DATE* range you are executing a text comparison. If the range holds true dates you need to convert the string in tbxDate to a true date, too.

Comment: You can't "dim the textbox as date". A Text Box contains text. Try `CDate(tbxDate)` or `CLng(Cdate(tbxDate))`

Comment: What @Variatus wrote. If your data are real dates, you need to ensure the textbox.**value** is a date.  The text box itself cannot be declared as a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of your code given below should work provided your DATE range contains true dates and tbxDate contains a string VBA can recognise as a date.

```
Private Sub cmdCalculate_Click()

    Dim Fun As Double
    
    Set SalesRange = Worksheets("SalesWS").Range("Sales[TOTAL]")
    Set DatesRange = Worksheets("SalesWS").Range("Sales[DATE]")
    Fun = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(SalesRange, DatesRange, ">=" & CLng(CDate(tbxDate.Value)))
    tbxBalance = Format(Fun, "#,##0.00")
End Sub
```

Remember that tbxBalance will cotnain a text string, not a number. Use Excel's NUMBERVALUE function to convert the formatted number you have in tbxBalance after the above code back to a number you can calculate with.

Comment: That trick fixed it. Now it works flawlessly. Thank you!